# How does attack take place when string is mutable?

Tags: string, mutable

It is common to hear that strings are immutable and this improves security. I understand the idea that since strings are final, their contents cannot be changed later. But even if the content could be changed, i think it is still safe as the code is written by developer instead of attacker.

Or else in practice, how does this attack are being done actually?

I saw an example online that indicated an attacker could bypass security if strings were mutable. I don't get it. The below code is written by developer. This is the part attacker can never touch. Whether strings are mutable or not attackers can never modify their values, right?

```
public class FileInputStream
{
 private String filename;
 public FileInputStream(String filename)
 {
  if (!allowedToReadFile(filename))
  throw new SecurityException();
  this.filename = filename;
  }
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are referring to is memory overflow, if a string is mutable, than it has a fixed memory size that cannot be changed, if it's not, one can enter a long enough value, that can overflow to other memory areas, and override content of other variables, hence introducing a security risk.

for example, let's say you have two variables in your program, var1 and var2, both are pre defined strings in the size of 3 bytes, than your memory allocation would look like:

```
[var1, var1, var1, var2, var2, var2]
```

and the actual values upon initialization are:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Then you query the user for input, and you get "aaaa", your memory stack would look like

```
[a,a,a,a,0,0]
```

meaning you have an overflow between the first variable to the second.

This is very language dependent.

Comment: it sounds somehow abstract, could you give an example of how to achieve attack about changing to open another unexpected file by this?

Comment: Thanks for your example. It is very detailed. 
So, this is assumed the attacker know how the memory is allocated and there is query input for attacker to do so. Did I understand you point right? Considering back to the example, If that's the cases, I am afraid this kind of attack would be very low chance in order to open another files because how could attackers know that precious to make an meaningful attack even if there really exist an input for him to overwrite?

Comment: That depends on the language you are using, if it's c, it is being complied to assembly and an attacker can reverse engineer and see the memory layout.

If you find this answer acceptable, please mark it at accepted, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I still dont see how this can make an meaningful attack with respect to the above examples, unless if  attack is only considered to just simply try to input a large enough input to mess the system at all.